# AbstractMethodError on UriBuilder when upgrading Jersey client 1.x to 2.x

Tags: java, jersey-client, jersey-2.0

We're in the process to upgrade our Web application (running on Tomcat7) from Jersey 1.7 to Jersey 2.4.1.
I managed to have the server-side working now, but the JUnit tests which are using jersey-client are throwing the AbstractMethodError:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:

```
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.<init>(JerseyWebTarget.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:69)
    at ******.test.resources.ResourceConfig.getResourceWithCredentialsAt(ResourceConfig.java:144)
    at ******.test.resources.ResourceConfig.getResourceAsUserAt(ResourceConfig.java:99)
    at ******.test.resources.UsersResourceTest.testGetAuthorizedUser(UsersResourceTest.java:251)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The project is maintained by maven, here are the pom's dependencies:

```
<!-- Our webapps are tomcat servlets -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Container to allow jersey running inside tomcat servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey core dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Media stuff -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON handling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Apparently I miss a concrete implementation of the UriBuilder class, but I have no clue what dependency I need to add for this. Also -- it works for the server-side, wut!?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137073/abstract-method-error/12137281#12137281

Comment: i have same problem like you...could provide your WEB-INF\lib ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that the **enunciate** library depends somehow on jersey 1.1.7. This caused parts of my code to compile fine while it was still depending on 1.1.7 API's.

I found it by doing a find:

```
find . -name *.pom -exec grep -Hn jersey {} \;
```

...in the ~/.m2 folder on jersey. This can only be done if your app is the only one using maven on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for that.  This was very helpful.  In my case, I needed to run `mvn clean` but you gave me a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

When you see this error, it means UriBuilder is being loaded from other libraries like cxf-2.1.3.jar. Just rename it to z-cxf-2.1.3.jar. It should work fine.In maven find which dependency is bring the jar and use something like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Find which all libraries contains cxf-2.1.3.jar and exclude the particular jar using maven exclude

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I see now that I also have 1.x versions of the jersey jar files inside the Maven Dependencies folder (eclipse). Mixed in with the 2.4.1 versions doesn't seem right. Strangely enough I don't have any 1.x jersey dep lingering around in the poms.

Comment: u dont need to have direct dependency some  plugin or transative dependency may have got those still u can exclude them