# AbstractMethodError while creating an index in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I want to create an index to store the url as a file name and using:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, analyzer);
FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(index));
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);

Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(newField("file_name", rs.getString("file_name"), 
        Field.Store.YES,
        Field.Index.ANALYZED));
writer.addDocument(doc);
```

However I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
       org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream.incrementToken()
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverterPerField.processFields(DocInverterPerField.java:133)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessorPerThread.processDocument(DocFieldProcessorPerThread.java:248)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:851)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.addDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:827)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:2022)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1996)
    at TextIndex1.main(TextIndex1.java:54)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, an abstract method call should be caught when compiling, if it's an issue in your code.  This coming up an a runtime error is generally due to importing incompatible jar versions.  What version are the Lucene jar version you are using?

See also, this question:  [Abstract Method Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137073/abstract-method-error)

Also, another note regarding Lucene versions, You appear to be using version 4.0 or later, in which case `Field` constructors using `Field.Index` are deprecated.  You should use one of the Field subclasses instead, like [`TextField`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html) or [`StringField`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html), for example.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to make a simple Index for text searches using Lucene 4.6

```
public void indexFilmTitle() {
    try {
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(AppConstants.INDEX_DIR));
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
        IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_46, analyzer);
        iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM sakila.film_text";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        int i=0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            i++;
            Document doc = new Document();
            Field id = new IntField("id", rs.getInt(1), Field.Store.YES);               
            doc.add(id);
            Field title = new TextField("title", rs.getString(2), Field.Store.YES);
            doc.add(title);
            writer.addDocument(doc);
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IndexManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IndexManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Note that you have to TextField.

And here is how to search:

```
public void searchFromFilm_Text(String keyword) {
    try {
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(AppConstants.INDEX_DIR)));
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_46, "title", analyzer);            
        Query query = parser.parse(keyword);
        System.out.println("Searching for: " + query.toString("title"));
        TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 100);             
        ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
        System.out.println(hits.length);
        for(ScoreDoc sdoc : hits)
        {
            Document doc = searcher.doc(sdoc.doc);
            System.out.println(doc.get("id"));
            System.out.println(doc.get("title"));             
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SearchManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SearchManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.....

Comment: i want to text search.but above code only return you give exact word to search. but i want search using only text.

Comment: May be you could try this: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/introduction-to-apache-lucene-for-full.html

Comment: Edited the answer to a working prototype for full text search