# lucene Field.Index.ANALYZED not working inVersion.LUCENE_40

Tags: java, lucene

**I am new for lucene i want indexing and searching filename an url give any possible answer.**

**My code as following:**

```
IndexWriter writer = null;
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(index);
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, analyzer);
writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("file_name", rs.getString("file_name"), Field.Store.NO,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
writer.addDocument(doc);
writer.optimize();
writer.commit();
writer.close();
```

**but at run time exception will come:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream.incrementToken()Z
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverterPerField.processFields(DocInverterPerField.java:133)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessorPerThread.processDocument(DocFieldProcessorPerThread.java:248)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:851)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.addDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:827)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:2022)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1996)
at TextIndex1.main(TextIndex1.java:63)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AbstractMethodError while creating an index in Lucene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280693/abstractmethoderror-while-creating-an-index-in-lucene)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to Lucene. You have some runtime error. The `AbstractMethodError` method error javadoc states:

`Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.`

Have a look at the libraries you're using when running the application.