# How to fix incompatible jars

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-injection, jvm

I'm using a gradle wrapper on `Gradle 4.10.1` and JVM `1.8.0_282 (AdoptOpenJDK 25.282-b08)` (quite old I know).

My `build.gradle` originally looked like this:

```
    compile "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:1.100.0"
    compile "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:1.104.1"
    compile "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.100.0"
```

This occurred after I added `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquerystorage:2.8.4`:

```
    compile "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:1.100.0"
    compile "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:1.104.1"
    compile "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.100.0"
    compile "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquerystorage:2.8.4"
```

All of my unit tests now fails with:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.InternalException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Panic! This is a bug!
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1123)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:435)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:900)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:811)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:675)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:564)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:534)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$ReleasingClientCall$1.onClose(ChannelPool.java:455)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:463)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:427)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:460)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:562)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:743)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:722)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Panic! This is a bug!
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport.newStream(Lio/grpc/MethodDescriptor;Lio/grpc/Metadata;Lio/grpc/CallOptions;[Lio/grpc/ClientStreamTracer;)Lio/grpc/internal/ClientStream;
    at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory$CallCredentialsApplyingTransport.newStream(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:159)
    at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.newStream(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:51)
    at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$CallTracingTransport.newStream(InternalSubchannel.java:673)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$PendingStream.createRealStream(DelayedClientTransport.java:366)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$PendingStream.access$400(DelayedClientTransport.java:351)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport.reprocess(DelayedClientTransport.java:309)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.updateSubchannelPicker(ManagedChannelImpl.java:899)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.access$5300(ManagedChannelImpl.java:118)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$LbHelperImpl$1UpdateBalancingState.run(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1479)
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95)
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
    at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$TransportListener.transportReady(InternalSubchannel.java:547)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ClientTransportLifecycleManager.notifyReady(ClientTransportLifecycleManager.java:44)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler$FrameListener.onSettingsRead(NettyClientHandler.java:909)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onSettingsRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:479)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$PrefaceFrameListener.onSettingsRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:702)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onSettingsRead(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:93)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readSettingsFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:542)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:263)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:160)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:174)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:378)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:242)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:438)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
```

This occurs without any code changes (just added that one dep to `build.gradle`), so I'm guessing this is an incompatible jar issue caused by the new dependency (as suggested by this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12137281/7242490)). Since I'm on gradle `4.10.1`, I can't resolve this with a pom. How does one go about resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of an incompatibility in the `grpc` JARs. You may have to modify the versions of the other `com.google.cloud` JARs to make sure that they are compatible. Here is [an issue from the upstream project](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/issues/903) where they recommend a [Google Cloud Libraries BOM](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/bom) to simplify managing versions of these libraries and hopefully avoid conflicts like this. Since you are on Gradle `4.10.1` you can either use [the feature preview for BOM support](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#bom-import) or use the [Spring Dependency Management plugin](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/).

Comment: Wow this worked. Ok thank you.